# Can't find a performance difference between AoS and SoA in C++

Tags: c++, performance

I am trying to understand the difference between AoS and SoA in practical terms.

I've tried this in C# and it yielded no result, so now I'm trying in C++.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

const int iterations = 40000000;

class Entity {
public:
    float a, b, c;
};

struct Entities {
public:
    float a[iterations];
    float b[iterations];
    float c[iterations];
};

void AoSTest(int iterations, Entity enArr[]);

void SoATest(int iterations, Entities* entities);

int main()
{
    Entity* enArr = new Entity[iterations];

    Entities* entities = new Entities;

    int A = rand() - 50;
    int B = rand() - 50;
    int C = rand() - 50;

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        enArr[i].a = A;
        enArr[i].b = B;
        enArr[i].c = C;

        entities->a[i] = A;
        entities->b[i] = B;
        entities->c[i] = C;
    }

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    AoSTest(iterations, enArr);
    //SoATest(iterations, entities);

    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = finish - start;

    //std::cout << std::to_string(elapsed.count()) + "time";
    std::cout << std::to_string(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(finish - start).count()) + "s";
}

void AoSTest(int iterations, Entity enArr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {   
        enArr[i].a = sqrt(enArr[i].a * enArr[i].c);
        enArr[i].c = sqrt(enArr[i].c * enArr[i].a);
        //std::cout << std::to_string(sqrt(enArr[i].a) + sqrt(enArr[i].b)) + "\n";
    }
}

void SoATest(int iterations, Entities* entities) {
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        entities->a[i] = sqrt(entities->a[i] * entities->c[i]);
        entities->c[i] = sqrt(entities->c[i] * entities->a[i]);
        //std::cout << std::to_string(sqrt(entities->a[i]) + sqrt(entities->b[i])) + "\n";
    }
}
```

My thought was that since data layout, in theory, should be different there should be a performance difference...

I don't understand why some say that there is a lot to gain here if it's so context sensitive as it seems to me thus far.

Is it completely dependent on SIMD or some specific optimization option?

I'm running it in Visual Studio.

Comment: How are you building it? Has stuff been optimised away? What happens on https://godbolt.org/?

Comment: Did you build it, with optimizations enabled? What was the output?

Comment: doesn't seem like there would be a performance difference. it more about how you model your memory - which is more understandable to you.

Answer (score 3):

I compiled your code with the intel compiler 18.0.1 and optimisation turned on (`-O3`). I added some return value, just to make sure nothing can be optimised away.

I found that Structure of Arrays (SoA) is approx twice as fast as  Array of Structures (AoS). This makes sence, since the quantity `B` will not be loaded into the cache from the slow memory (RAM) if you use the SoA approch, but it will occupy cache with the AoS approach. Please not that I changed the time resolution to nanoseconds. Otherwise, I always get `0s` as output.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
const int iterations = 40000000;

class Entity {
  public:
    float a, b, c;
};

struct Entities {
  public:
    float a[iterations];
    float b[iterations];
    float c[iterations];
};

int AoSTest(int iterations, Entity enArr[]);

int SoATest(int iterations, Entities* entities);

int main() {
    Entity* enArr = new Entity[iterations];

    Entities* entities = new Entities;

    int A = rand() - 50;
    int B = rand() - 50;
    int C = rand() - 50;

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        enArr[i].a = A;
        enArr[i].b = B;
        enArr[i].c = C;

        entities->a[i] = A;
        entities->b[i] = B;
        entities->c[i] = C;
    }

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    //    const auto ret = AoSTest(iterations, enArr);
    const auto ret = SoATest(iterations, entities);

    auto finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = finish - start;

    std::cout << std::to_string(std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(finish - start).count()) + "ns "
              << "ret=" << ret;
}

int AoSTest(int iterations, Entity enArr[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        enArr[i].a = sqrt(enArr[i].a * enArr[i].c);
        enArr[i].c = sqrt(enArr[i].c * enArr[i].a);
    }
    return enArr[iterations - 1].c;
}

int SoATest(int iterations, Entities* entities) {
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        entities->a[i] = sqrt(entities->a[i] * entities->c[i]);
        entities->c[i] = sqrt(entities->c[i] * entities->a[i]);
    }
    return entities->c[iterations - 1];
}
```

Comment: I am using Visual Studio and put Runtime Checks to default and set Optimization to Ox and saw that AoS was 0s and SoA was 8s? I don't know how you are compiling it the way you are. I am trying to figure out a way to understand it's the application, and I just feel having to compile the code with a specific compiler and with a very specific setting is weird and makes it pretty much useless?

Comment: I just gave reference to the compiler I used for the sake of completeness. The results should not vary too much with respect to the compiler. Notwithstanding, you will find huge differences, if you compile to debug or release code. You need to enable the highest release optimisation level (which is for all mayor compilers -O3), in order to measure the best case performance.

Answer (score 0):

SoA is beneficial to load or store your data with SIMD intrinsics, see e.g. https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=AVX&cats=Load&expand=3317 for intel AVX.

Now in your specific case, you need to provide more information regarding the compiler options etc., but probably your specific case is not easy for the compiler to vectorize.
I would suggest that you use independent instructions for each entry (here c depends on a) to perform more tests.

Comment: Yeah SIMD makes sense to me, but shouldn't SoA have an effect either way? It makes zero sense to me that these two constructions run the same. I am a complete noob in this area, but if it is the case that it's so specific then compilers absolutely suck.